# Network-less "vault" tool

Tags: android, security, encryption

I am running a Samsung S7 Edge on Android 7.0 **non-rooted.** What I am looking for is essentially a *vault* or encrypted space on my phone requiring a passcode or passphrase to access. Furthermore, I am looking for an application that is capable of ascertaining images (via **HTTPS**) on my local LAN.

What I wish to do is open up an image, or file to the local LAN via a Web URL (Let's say `https://192.168.0.1/files`), and use the application to directly access said file, and store it in an encrypted manner within the app.

If I was to save a photo for example, I would want to bypass the Gallery/Google Photo application entirely and store the data directly into the app; sort of an **incognito mode**, but for files.

Needs:

- Run on Android 7.0
- Does not require root permissions
- Must allow me to export images, files and videos at certain times

Wants:

- Backup facility (of the storage)
- Cross platform, with Linux
- 2 step authentication perhaps (via email)
- Developers have a good reputation
- Only allows connections to known hosts/IP (I don't want this app being able to communicate anywhere else apart from where I state)

Presently I am using "Audio Manager" for my download needs, however the application has many complaints of data being lost.